# Apply a match function repeatedly to multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r, function, match

I need to **sum the overlaps between three dataframes and repeat this action multiple times.**

To be more specific, I want to count the overlaps between where insects forage, the plants they forage on, and where those plants are found.

So far I can do this, using indexing, for just one insect species out of a list of species, but I need to do it for multiple species (this will later be done on far more species and plant families so I don't want to do it by hand).

**Example dataframes:**

Plant habitats (location):

```
plantloc <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=5,nrow=5, dimnames=list(NULL, c("plantfamily", "hedge", "margin", "arablefields", "grassfields"))))
plantloc$plantfamily <- c("Aceraceae", "Boraginaceae", "Dipsacaceae", "Lamiaceae", "Umbelliferae")
plantloc$hedge <- c(1,1,1,1,1)
plantloc$margin <- c(0,1,0,1,1)
plantloc$arablefields <- c(0,1,0,1,1)
plantloc$grassfields <- c(0,1,1,1,1)
```

Bumblebee forage plants:

```
bbfpl <-data.frame(matrix(ncol=6,nrow=14, dimnames=list(NULL, c("species","Aceraceae", "Boraginaceae", "Dipsacaceae", "Lamiaceae", "Umbelliferae"))))
bbfpl$species <- c("Bombus_distinguendus","Bombus_hortorum","Bombus_humilis","Bombus_jonellus","Bombus_lapidarius","Bombus_lucorum","Bombus_muscorum","Bombus_pascuorum","Bombus_pratorum","Bombus_ruderarius","Bombus_ruderatus","Bombus_soroeensis","Bombus_sylvarum","Bombus_terrestris")
bbfpl$Aceraceae <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
bbfpl$Boraginaceae <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
bbfpl$Dipsacaceae <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
bbfpl$Lamiaceae <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
bbfpl$Umbelliferae <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
```

Bumblebee foraging habitats:

```
bbfhab <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=5,nrow=14, dimnames=list(NULL, c("species", "hedge", "margin", "arablefields", "grassfields"))))
bbfhab$species <- c("Bombus_distinguendus","Bombus_hortorum","Bombus_humilis","Bombus_jonellus","Bombus_lapidarius","Bombus_lucorum","Bombus_muscorum","Bombus_pascuorum","Bombus_pratorum","Bombus_ruderarius","Bombus_ruderatus","Bombus_soroeensis","Bombus_sylvarum","Bombus_terrestris")
bbfhab$hedge <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
bbfhab$margin <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
bbfhab$arablefields <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
bbfhab$grassfields <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

**Using Bombus_sylvarum  as an example:**

1. Match the plant families used by Bombus_sylvarum (i.e. the column names of *bbfpl* where B_sylv has a 1) with the plant family column of *plantloc*, and return the row index of those plant families

```
    match(colnames(bbfpl)[which(bbfpl[13,] == 1)],plantloc$plantfamily)
```

2. Match the foraging habitats used by Bombus_sylvarum  (i.e. the column names of *bbfhab* where B_sylv has a 1) with the habitat columns of *plantloc*, and return the column index of those habitats

```
    match(colnames(bbfhab)[which(bbfhab[13,] == 1)],colnames(plantloc))
```

3. Use the two matches above to index the habitats (columns) and plant families (rows) in *plantloc* that are used by Bombus_sylvarum, and sum all values in these indexed locations. This gives the total number of overlaps. In this case it's 8.

```
    sum(plantloc[match(colnames(bbfpl)[which(bbfpl[13,] == 1)],plantloc$plantfamily) , match(colnames(bbfhab)[which(bbfhab[13,] == 1)],colnames(plantloc))])
```

I can do each individual step for all 14 species, e.g.:

```
apply(bbfpl, 1,
      function(x){
      match(colnames(bbfpl)[which(x==1)],plantloc$plantfamily)
      })
```

but I can't work out how to put both steps together.

**Question:**

How do I do this for all 14 bumblebee species and put the results in a new dataframe (first column = bumblebee species, second column = result)?

lapply? loop? purrr?

I have scoured similar questions but haven't managed to solve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstand the question... I don't know what would stop you from wrapping your step 3. into a function that iterates through `seq_len(nrow(bbfpl))` to replace 13 by 1:14 to get those sums, but here is a `data.table` approach that might be more efficient:

```r
library(data.table)
BBFPL <- melt(data.table(bbfpl), id.vars = "species", variable.name = "plantfamily", value.name = "fam.value")
BBFHAB <- melt(data.table(bbfhab), id.vars = "species")
BBF <- merge(BBFPL, BBFHAB, by="species", allow.cartesian=TRUE)
BBF[, idx := .I] # to preserve order
PL <- melt(data.table(plantloc), id.vars = "plantfamily")[value==1]
setkey(PL, plantfamily, variable)
setkey(BBF, plantfamily, variable)
out <- BBF[PL][fam.value*value*i.value==1]
setkey(out, idx) # reorder result
out[, list(sum=.N), by="species"][]
#>                  species sum
#>  1: Bombus_distinguendus   3
#>  2:      Bombus_hortorum  10
#>  3:       Bombus_humilis   6
#>  4:      Bombus_jonellus   5
#>  5:    Bombus_lapidarius  10
#>  6:       Bombus_lucorum  10
#>  7:      Bombus_muscorum   3
#>  8:     Bombus_pascuorum  10
#>  9:      Bombus_pratorum   9
#> 10:    Bombus_ruderarius   5
#> 11:     Bombus_ruderatus   4
#> 12:    Bombus_soroeensis   3
#> 13:      Bombus_sylvarum   8
#> 14:    Bombus_terrestris  10
```

Comment: Your suggestion of "wrapping your step 3. into a function that iterates through seq_len(nrow(bbfpl)) to replace 13 by 1:14 to get those sums" is something I'd been trying to do but hadn't managed yet. Thanks for the data.table suggestion.

Comment: Could you explain how to do that please?

Comment: `sapply(seq_len(nrow(bbfpl)), function(i){
    sum(plantloc[match(colnames(bbfpl)[which(bbfpl[i,] == 1)],plantloc$plantfamily) , 
                 match(colnames(bbfhab)[which(bbfhab[i,] == 1)], colnames(plantloc))])})`

Comment: this is beautiful! Thanks. I've used it as it's the shortest solution, so I've accepted your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `tidyverse` packages `dplyr` and `tidyr` to transform the data into a convenient form for joining together.

```
library(tidyverse)    # Load tidyverse packages (including dplyr and tidyr)

# Create three matching tables:

## plantfamilies matched to habitats
pf_hab <-
    plantloc %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -plantfamily, names_to = "habitat") %>%    # Convert to one row per (plantfamily, habitat)
    filter(value == 1) %>%                                         # Keep the 1's, remove the 0's
    select(-value)                                                 # Drop the value column (since it's now all 1's)

## Bumblebee species matched to plant families
bb_pf <-
    bbfpl %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -species, names_to = "plantfamily") %>%    # Convert to one row per (species, plantfamily)
    filter(value == 1) %>%                                         # Keep the 1's, remove the 0's
    select(-value)                                                 # Drop the value column (since it's now all 1's)

## Bumblebee species matched to habitats
bb_hab <-
    bbfhab %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -species, names_to = "habitat") %>%    # Convert to one row per (species, habitat)
    filter(value == 1) %>%                                     # Keep the 1's, remove the 0's
    select(-value)                                             # Drop the value column (since it's now all 1's)

# Join them into a single table 
bb_pf_hab <-
    bb_pf %>%
    inner_join(bb_hab) %>%    # Join bb_pf to bb_hab (automatically joins on the matching column name, "species")
    inner_join(pf_hab)        # Join that result to pf_hab (automatically joins on the matching column names, "plantfamily" and "habitat")

# If we want, we can use this table to look up the matches for a given species, e.g., Bombus sylvarum
bb_pf_hab %>% filter(species == 'Bombus_sylvarum')

# Output:
#   species         plantfamily  habitat    
#   <chr>           <chr>        <chr>      
# 1 Bombus_sylvarum Dipsacaceae  hedge      
# 2 Bombus_sylvarum Dipsacaceae  grassfields
# 3 Bombus_sylvarum Lamiaceae    hedge      
# 4 Bombus_sylvarum Lamiaceae    margin     
# 5 Bombus_sylvarum Lamiaceae    grassfields
# 6 Bombus_sylvarum Umbelliferae hedge      
# 7 Bombus_sylvarum Umbelliferae margin     
# 8 Bombus_sylvarum Umbelliferae grassfields

# Count the matches for each species
bb_pf_hab %>%
    group_by(species) %>%     # Assign groups for aggregation
    summarize(Count = n())    # Count the number in each group

# Output:
#   species               Count
#   <chr>                 <int>
# 1 Bombus_distinguendus      3
# 2 Bombus_hortorum          10
# 3 Bombus_humilis            6
# 4 Bombus_jonellus           5
# 5 Bombus_lapidarius        10
# 6 Bombus_lucorum           10
# 7 Bombus_muscorum           3
# 8 Bombus_pascuorum         10
# 9 Bombus_pratorum           9
# 10 Bombus_ruderarius        5
# 11 Bombus_ruderatus         4
# 12 Bombus_soroeensis        3
# 13 Bombus_sylvarum          8
# 14 Bombus_terrestris       10
```

Here's a more concise version of the same approach:

```
library(tidyverse)    

# Create matching table based on which numeric columns have non-zero value
get_matching_table <- function(data, names_to) {
    data %>% pivot_longer(where(is.numeric), names_to) %>%
             filter(value != 0) %>% select(-value)
}

# Join matching tables, joining on columns with matching names
bb_pf_hab <-
    list(get_matching_table(bbfpl, names_to = 'plantfamily'),
         get_matching_table(bbfhab, names_to = 'habitat'),
         get_matching_table(plantloc, names_to = 'habitat')) %>%
    reduce(inner_join)

# Count matches by species
bb_pf_hab %>% group_by(species) %>% summarize(Count = n())
```

Comment: Note that `%>%` is the pipeline operator that takes the previous result (the left-hand side of the operator) and supplies it as the first argument of the next function (the right-hand side of the operator).

Comment: For tidyverse functions, the first argument is usually a data.frame, so this lets you write your code in a very readable way, as a series of transformations on a data frame, listed in the order that they actually happen.  (Avoiding the `g(f(x))` syntax, where `f` is applied first but is written second.)

Comment: Thank you for your solution! When I try the more concise version, I get the following error: "This tidyselect interface doesn't support predicates yet.
i Contact the package author and suggest using `eval_select()`." Do you not get the same error?

Comment: @user39683 It works fine for me.  I suspect you may have an earlier verison of one of the tidyverse packages.  Try running `tidyverse::tidyverse_update()` and see if it lists any packages as having updates available.